# EdgeDriver - Cannot change window size in Edge

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am using the [EdgeDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.EdgeDriver/3.14393.0) for running automation tests on my browser (Edge 38.14393.0.0). My tests are in C#, so I am using the .NET driver:

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
    
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Normal;
    
RemoteWebDriver driver = return new EdgeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

driver.SetDocumentSize(new Size(800, 600)); // HERE!
```

#### The error

This code is the one I run at the beginning of the test. And it fails at the last line with:

> Class Initialization method
> `Web.TestSuite.UIRendering.RenderingTestSuiteEdge.TestClassInitialize`
> threw exception. `System.InvalidOperationException`:
> `System.InvalidOperationException`: A window size operation failed
> because the window is not currently available.

With this stack trace:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 1126
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 920
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWindow.set_Size(Size value) in ...
```

**FYI** Be aware that I have other tests running on Chrome and IE11 using their respective drivers. When I call `SetDocumentSize` on those, I get no errors.

#### Open issues

I could find some open issues related to this problem:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9340417/
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8778306/

#### Questions

So, these are my questions:

- Has anybody succeeded in setting the window size in Edge?
- Is this problem I am hitting a known issue? If so, is it fixed? The referenced issues (which look similar) are still open and no status provided.
- Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Try one of those for C#:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Although I encounter that error for different reason (like the one here -> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10319887/).

Now I kill all process of the driver & edge before each test so hopefully it will be resolved like that:

```
try
{
     foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftWebDriver"))
     {
           process.Kill();
     }

     foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdge"))
     {
           process.Kill();
     }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Also if you run them on remote machine via RDP for example it will make the same error when you close the RDP. This is the current workaround that I found for it:

```
Create a batch file with this code:

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)

Create a desktop shortcut to this file. To do this, right-click the batch
file and select Send to | Desktop (create shortcut).

In the shortcut properties, click Advanced and select Run as administrator.
```

Now, when you need to disconnect from Remote Desktop, double-click this shortcut on the remote computer (in the Remote Desktop window).

Thanks to https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html for the script.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1250, 720));
```

Comment: Ahh.  Yes, sorry, that is for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can set window size for Microsoft Edge as shown below. *`-window-size` and `window-size` also work:

```cs
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1024,768");
EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

And, you can also set window size for Microsoft Edge with the code below according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```cs
EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
```

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863624/how-to-run-headless-firefox-in-the-window-size-1920-1080-in-c/77086252#77086252) explains it more.