# How to run headless Firefox in the window size (1920, 1080) in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox, headless, window-size

How can I run headless Firefox in the window size (1920, 1080) in C#?

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
firefoxOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");

FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);

firefoxDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

firefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
var size = firefoxDriver.Manage().Window.Size; //{Width = 1366 Height = 768}
```

Any suggestions, how to run in full HD? I
need to set here...

For example with chrome working correctly:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("headless");
options.AddArguments("window-size=1920x1080");
```

Comment: This has been an issue in the Firefox driver, but maximizing still doesn't seem to work. Just tried `firefoxDriver.Manage().Window.FullScreen()`, but that gives the same result.

Comment: According to this post the issue should have been fixed:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/993.  
But that doesn't seem te case.

Answer (score 4):

I find it:

```
firefoxOptions.AddArguments("-width=1920");
firefoxOptions.AddArguments("-height=1080");
```

but if you call somewhere in your code this:

```
webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

then set to default resolution.. {Width = 1366 Height = 768}

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Dimension Class after driver object creation.

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(1920,1080);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

Comment: Not good, there are other webdrivers (mobile with different resolutions, desktop)

Comment: To handle other driver just make it condition specific 

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run firefox without GUI on ubuntu after a couple of search, here you can try

```
# install Xvfb (X Virtual Frame Buffer) and related Fonts 
$ sudo apt-get install xvfb 
$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic 

# Setup Display 
$ export DISPLAY=:1 

# run Xvfb in background, set screen resolution as HDMI (1920x1080, 24 dpi), run on display:1 
$ Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 &

# Run firefox
firefox &

# OR
firefox --headless &
```

Answer (score 0):

### <**Chrome**>

*`-window-size` and `window-size` also work:

```cs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

*This code below also works according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```cs
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
```

### <**Microsoft Edge**>

*`-window-size` and `window-size` also work:

```cs
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

*This code below also works according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```cs
EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
```

### <**Firefox**>

*-width and -height also work while `width` and `height` don't work:

```cs
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("--width=1920");
options.AddArguments("--height=1080");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

*This code below also works according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```cs
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
```